# Dispose a form in ApplicationContext before calling Application.Restart

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I have a winforms application that uses a custom application context which provides the framework to run the application in the system tray.

```
public partial class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private IContainer components;
    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon = null;

    /// the main application form, which may never be shown
    private AppForm appForm = null;

    public MyApplicationContext() 
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon(components)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip(),
            Icon = Properties.Resources.icon2a,
            Text = "Application",
            Visible = true
        };

        appForm = new AppForm();
    }
}
```

The application watches for changes to a config file, and restarts itself as necessary.

```
private void requestRestart()
{
    /// dispose the application context
    this.Dispose(); 
    Application.Restart();
}
```

I have to dispose the application context before restarting as there are resources which will be required by the new instance of the application. However `requestRestart()` may be called from **another thread.** So I can't dispose of `appForm` in the `ApplicationContext.Dispose()` method or directly in the restart method, or I will get a cross-threading exception.

If the form has been shown before the restart when the user clicks on the tray icon which calls `appForm.Show()` then `appForm.Dispose(true)` will be called automatically.  Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Dispose will be called automatically if the form is shown using the Show method.

Otherwise, if the form is never shown, the GC finalizer calls `Dispose(false)`.

How can I make sure this form is disposed before the restart?

Comment: Do you have to new-up the form in the constructor?  Can you new up the form in the same method that you are currently calling Show() ?

Comment: Suggestion: Briefly show then hide the form

Comment: @JacobSeleznev I had that thought, but it seemed hackish?

Comment: @axlj are you suggesting to just `using(){}` the form in show form method? The appForm class holds data that needs to persist through the life of the application.

Comment: @khargoosh Yessir -- if I understand correctly, you have a method that gets called when you right click on the tray icon?  In that method you call `appForm.Show()`.  So why not just wrap that in a `using` block and instantiate the form there?

Comment: @axlj it's probably a good way to go, I will have to refactor data out of the class though.

Comment: You'll be thankful that you did that later anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you remove `appForm.Show()` out of the constructor and place it into the method that gets called from the tray icon.

Inside your tray icon open form method, wrap `appForm.Show()` in a using block:

```
using (appForm = new AppForm()) {
    appForm.Show();
}
```

This way the form will dispose of itself whenever it closes.

Furthermore, place the following in the `requestRestart()` method:

```
appForm?.Close();
```

This will make sure that your form is closed whenever the context forces a restart.

If you're not using the latest version of .NET, the following will achieve the same thing:

```
if (appForm != null)
    appForm.Close();
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is a full example.  This answer is a little more opinionated about how you handle your background tasks, but I think you'll find it works pretty well.

Explanations are inlined as comments.

In your Program.cs:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int restartCount = 0;
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var applicationCtx = new MyApplicationContext();

    applicationCtx.RestartRequested += (o, e) =>
    {
        restartCount++; //this is just here so my program would stop restarting
        if (restartCount > 5) Application.Exit();

        Application.Restart();
    };

    Application.Run(applicationCtx);
}
```

Then in MyApplicationContext.cs:

```
internal class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
    private IContainer components;
    private AppForm appForm;

    public event EventHandler RestartRequested;

    public MyApplicationContext()
    {
        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon()
        {
            ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip { Text = "Open Form" },
            Text = "Application",
            Visible = true,
            Icon = new Icon("icon.ico")
        };

        appForm = new AppForm();

        notifyIcon.DoubleClick += (o, e) =>
        {
            appForm.Show();
        };

        RestartRequested += (o, e) =>
        {
            appForm?.Close();  //Close() will dispose the form as well.
            notifyIcon?.Dispose();
        };

        BackgroundWork();
    }

    private void BackgroundWork()
    {
        Task.Run<bool>(() => //Here we are telling Task to run a background operation and return a bool
        {
            //this body will run in a separate thread
            Thread.Sleep(5000);  //this represents your background work
            var restart = true;  //whatever result the bg work yields
            return restart;
        }).ContinueWith((task) =>  //task is an instance of Task from above containing the result fromm the background work
        {
            var shouldRestart = task.Result;  // Result is the value you returned in the body Run body above
            if (shouldRestart) RestartRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        },
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); //This will return on the UI thread now, no need to worry about thread boundaries
    }
}
```

Comment: It's called null propagation -- There is an article about it on msdn here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx but googling it might yield you more fruitful details.

Comment: thanks for the example, interesting and not at all what I'm familiar with.  Does the `RestartRequested` event handler in `MyApplicationContext` always execute before the handler in `Main()`? All of my background work is started via either IOCP for network communication events or the arrival of a windows message.

Comment: Based on the documentation, the delegates are invoked in the order in which they appear.  In this case, the `MyApplicationContext` class will always get hit first because the assignment is inside the constructor.  Any external event handlers will always be added after the internal event handler.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx